# How to set the image/png mime type in google drive from google apps script?

Tags: base64, google-apps-script, mime-types, google-drive-api

I have an image encoded as base64 blob that I can serve up successfully from Google Apps Script - as per [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brucemcpherson/HW2Ae/)

I'm trying to now save this as an image on Google Drive using Google apps script. Although I can write the file, and when I download it access it, it is indeed an image, the google docs viewer cannot preview it. Here's the code to save it - which works, and correctly reports the content type as image/png.

```
 function writeToDrive() {
      var blobOb = blobObGet("googleLogoBlob");
      if (!blobOb.error) {
          var imgBlob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(blobOb.blob),"image/png",blobOb.name + ".png" );
          Logger.log (imgBlob.getContentType());
          var file = DocsList.createFile(imgBlob);
      }
    }
```

How do I access the file metadata from google apps script so as to set the correct mime/type for the the google docs  viewer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is probably related to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1239) with jpegs...
The issue has been posted on april 2012 but it's not fixed yet.